# UPS graceful shutdown - how to automatically restart the server when the power is back?

Tags: bios, power, shutdown

I have a home server (Intel NUC i7) supported by a basic UPS (Eaton Ellipse Pro 650).

The UPS is connected to the server via USB and is configured to gracefully shut it down when its power runs off. But how to automatically restart the server when the power is back?

Note:

1. If I disable the graceful shutdown then [there is a setting I can set in the server's BIOS](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000054773/intel-nuc/intel-nuc-mini-pcs.html) so that it restarts automatically when the power is back on. Note the issue here comes from "With these settings, intentionally shutting down the system will result in the system staying powered down" as specified in the link above
2. I have found this [old question](https://serverfault.com/questions/617762/automatic-power-on-after-graceful-shutdown-on-ups) asking the same thing, part of the answer saying "a single UPS can restore the previous power state following an outage (this is the default in the HP ProLiant BIOS as well)". I have not found this BIOS setting on my NUC and there is no configuration in the UPS to enable "restore to previous power state"... Maybe my UPS is too basic?
3. [This](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1525772-ups-power-state-after-power-loss-and-battery-depletion) is also asking the same, an answer being to use the Wake-on-LAN functionality, but then I can just as well go and press the power button...

Comment: When my UPS shuts down the main computer, it stays OFF until I tun it back on. You would need to fashion a power switch on a power bar that can sense power and turn the computer on that way. It is just as simple to turn it back on because you do not know how long the outage will last.

Comment: The software "Eaton Intelligent Power Protector (IPP)" can be set to put the computer into sleep. If the BIOS interprets this as "intentionally shutting down the system", there is nothing you can from the computer side. You can in this case only create another server, or script your router, to send Wake-On-Lan when power comes back up.

Comment: A little higher end UPS will have options to handle this. I am not sure of the exact feature name but essentially, when power is restored, it will wait for the battery to recharge to a threshold level and then it will power cycle the electrical outlets to power devices back on. Your server should be set to always power on after power failure. This is very common with professional server setups.

Comment: @Appleoddity The issue is that a graceful shutdown is not interpreted as a power failure as specified in my first point

Comment: @Appleoddity, what would be a "little higher end UPS" in my case?